# How to assign multiple threads to similar controls on windows form?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How do I assign different threads to more than one control on a windows form using C# .Net 3.5?
I want say 3 textboxes to each be connected to a thread running the same 
function, say count the number of odd numbers in an array.

Ideally the usage would look something like:

```
//count the number of odd numbers in an array and when 
//done set the textbox to the value
void AssignTaskToTexbox( TextBox textbox, int[] array);
```

The code that can run in the thread assigned to the TextBox would have a signature like:

```
int GetCount(int[] array);

//usage:
AsssignTaskToTexbox( textbox1, array1);
AsssignTaskToTexbox( textbox2, array2);
```

After each call of the AssignTaskToTextBox the task would be assigned asynchronously to the
textbox. It would then go of to do the count and set the text when it is done i.e. the program could go
of to do other things and when the tasks are complete the textboxes would be updated in the background.
I am new to threading and would like some pointers as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to assign a thread to a control. All of the UI runs on a single thread, called the "main" or "UI" thread.

And there's not much point in running the same code multiple times, even if it's happening "simultaneously" on multiple threads. It sounds like to me that you just need to calculate the result once and display it in multiple textboxes. That requires only one background thread.

Either way, don't over-complicate things. Use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component to make spinning off computational tasks to background threads easier on yourself. Drop one on your form, add a handler for its `DoWork` event (where you do the computation), and then another handler for its `RunWorkerCompleted` (where you display the results of the computation).

If you have trouble following that, there's a great example of how to make it tick at the bottom of the linked documentation. Just modify it to your needs.

Comment: What I am trying to do is start an individiual thread for each of the controls. When the calculation is complete the textbox will show the results of that specific calculation eg texbox1 will show the sum of all the elements, textbox 2 the number of odd numbers etc. The idea is all the calculations will run on their own threads simultaneously and the textbox only updated once the task for that specific thread is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is add something like the following to the end of the code you are running in the thread:

```
string  v = // a value that took a long time to calculate
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { textbox.Value = v; }, null );
```

The idea is to run the calculations on an independent thread, then put the results into the TextBox **using the UI thread**.

(Take care.  I'm translating from Java to C# and this isn't an area of C# I know well.  The idea is sound. but I don't really know the classes and methods, I'guessing at the lambda syntax, and I didn't check the code in an IDE.)